# Which phrase about medical situations reads better and why?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, adjective-order

> When dealing with emergency medical situations

or

> When dealing with medical emergency situations

Comment: How about "When dealing with medical emergencies"?

Comment: I would put "emergency" first, since it is a time-related modifier.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fields of medicine is "Emergency Medicine." This refers the triage and rapid-response work done in emergency rooms.

Some conditions are "medical emergencies." For example, if you eat something which sends you into anaphylactic shock, that might be described as a medical emergency. If you call your regular physician and get an after-hours message, it will often include something similar to: "If you are experiencing a medical emergency, go to an ER or Urgent Care center."

Either word order is correct, and each refers to something urgent, bad, and medical. However, the first will focus more on the practice of emergency medicine, and the second will focus more on the emergency.

In general, you *probably* want the first, which sounds very slightly more natural.